# Crop image in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I try to crop image in windows phone 8 App. 
I use following namespace

```
xmlns:y="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Media.Imaging;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
```

And write content panel like this.

```
        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="200" Margin="97,153,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200">
                <Image.Source>
                    <y:CroppedBitmap 
         SourceRect="30 0 75 50">
                        <y:CroppedBitmap.Source>
                            <BitmapImage UriSource="/Assets/image.jpg"/>
                        </y:CroppedBitmap.Source>
                    </y:CroppedBitmap>
                </Image.Source>
            </Image>


        </Grid>
```

Error is occurred.

```
error : The tag 'CroppedBitmap' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:System.Windows.Media.Imaging;assembly=Microsoft.Phone'.
```

If anyone can solve this or do this using another way. please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Use WriteableBitmapExtension library instead which has inbuilt crop functionality.

http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/